# JPA2/Hibernate Order By using field in referenced table/object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am attempting to use ORDER BY in a query to sort by a field in the referenced object.  For example, with the following classes:

```
@Entity
class Phone
{
    @Id
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    Person owner;
}

@Entity
class Person
{
    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;
}
```

I want to list all phones, ordered by the owner's name.
This works for the most part, except it excludes phones that don't have an owner.  (IE., owner is null).

For example,

```
{
    etc...
    // Count number of phones in database
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Phone");
    Number n = (Number)q.getSingleResult();
    // N shows 10 phones

    q = em.createQuery("SELECT row FROM Phone row ORDER BY row.owner.name");
    List<Phone> phones = q.getResultList();
    // phones.size() is only 5???
}
```

Using *ORDER BY COALESCE(row.owner.name, '')* doesn't fetch the missing rows either!

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: You need to specify an outer-join there. When you include the owner in the query you're implicitly doing an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

By using an implicit inner Join, you reduce the number of results to the number of items having representations in both tables.

Try this:

```
SELECT row FROM Phone row LEFT OUTER JOIN row.owner o ORDER BY o.name
```

o will be null if there's no Owner of the Phonenumber, so might need to use COALESCE with the OUTER Join...

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.